# Aspnet LinqtoTwitter - PageCycle Issues

Tags: asp.net, webforms, twitter

I am currently working on the linqtotwitter library.

I am using cookies to store the token and key. My problem isnt with the api as much. It is more with ASP net and page life cycle.

The problem i have with my webform app is the same with the aspnet webform defaultasp sample same at linqtotwitter site.

This is how the api works

You pass the Credentials to Authorize object to Twitter context in a nut shell.

In the sample you authorize and etc. Once the page load the auth.screenname label is changed to your twitter handle because you authenicated and it passed the auth.credentials to the twittercontext.

This is where my problem is.  If I hit refresh the label is cleared out but I am still authenicated with twitter so I can post except i can not get values from the auth objects.

How would I keep the state on a refresh so I keep something like the auth.screenname or something else in memory.

I think i would need to preload the twitter authorized context but I have no idea about doing that.

I do not think using a hidden form element is proper because your masking the underlying problem.

If you want to see what  linqtotwitter is, it is  at http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could throw the tokens into `Session` if you have it enabled, that might solve your issue.